# when should we use "extern constant" in C?

Tags: c, compilation, constants, extern, linkage

I have seen several posts about extern constant in C. But it is not still clear for me that What is the use of "extern constant" in C?; and when we should use extern constant?
Regards...

Comment: Never. There is no "constant" keyword in C.

Comment: I can't find the right chapter and verse right now, but I believe global consts are extern by default in C, and static by default in C++.

Comment: Use extern when you want to use the variable from another file. The linker will get the variable from the appropriate file automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You use extern constant when you want to tell the compiler that a symbol is defined in another file, hence it won't throw undefined reference errors.

Of course you must have that symbol defined (whether it is a constant or a function) somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You use extern const, first, to have only one definition so you can handly change the value in one place for all references, and, in second place, to avoid wasting memory allocating the same constant value in all modules where you use it.

Comment: @ Damiano ,many thanks for the comment. As I understand, I can't give several values to an extern constant variable in several files and it should be initialized just once in a file.

Comment: extern for variables means: " Hey compiler it exists a variable of this kind defined elsewhere just trust me". Then the linker will sort things out.